# Convert this C# code to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting an application from C# to VB, but I got stuck in this line:

```
byte[] picData = sdr2["foto"] as byte[] ?? null;
```

Can any one help me to convert it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the point of `?? null`?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with it? The `?? null` seems superfluent, the rest is straightforward.

Comment: Wow .. null coalescing operator and is used to return null ! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim picData As Byte() = If(TryCast(sdr2("foto"), Byte()), Nothing)
```

For conversions like this one, you can rely on a plethora of online converters to do a (relatively) decent job.

Check out http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ or any number of others, have a Google at it.

Be aware, however that your null-coalescing operator states, in this case, that if `sdr2["foto"] as byte[]` returns `null`, then return `null`... You might want to fix that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/):

```
Dim picData As Byte() = If(TryCast(sdr2("foto"), Byte()), Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [useful tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to translate VB <-> C#

```
Dim picData As Byte() = If(TryCast(sdr2("foto"), Byte()), Nothing)
```

As stated first by MarcinJuraszek, `?? null` doesn't mean anything here, so you should use :

```
Dim picData As Byte() = TryCast(sdr2("foto"), Byte())
```